# Complement of a multiplicative set

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, commutative-algebra

> **Definition**
>
> Let $A$ be a commutative ring with $1$. $S\subseteq A$ is a *multiplicative set* if $$1\in S~\text{and}~f,g\in S\Rightarrow fg\in S$$ An ideal $P\subset A$ is *prime* if its complement $A\setminus P$ is a multiplicative set.

I've been given the following exercise:

> Give an example of a ring $A$ and a multiplicative set $S$ such that $A\setminus S$ is not a prime ideal. Read again the definition of multiplicative set and prime ideal, and check that all is right.

I want to know if I've solved this exercise. Here we go:

Some observations:

- Let $A=\Bbb Z$ and $S=\{1,2,2^2,\ldots\}$. $S$ is multiplicative since $2^i, 2^j\in S$ and $2^{i+j}\in S$ for natural numbers $i,j$. $A\setminus S$ is not an ideal, since $3,5\in A\setminus S$ but $3+5=8\not\in A\setminus S$.
- Let $A=\Bbb Z$ and $S=\{-1,1\}$. Then $A\setminus S=\bigcup_{p\in A} (p)$ is the union of prime ideals in $A$. This is not a prime ideal, since by Bezout we may form $1$ by a linear combination $ap+bq=1$ for distinct primes $p,q\in A$, which cannot happen in prime ideals.
- For any ring $A$ let $S=A\setminus P$ for some prime ideal $P\subset A$. Then $A\setminus(A\setminus P)=P$ is a prime ideal.
- If $A\setminus S=I\subseteq A$ is an ideal it has to be a prime ideal. Suppose $a,b\not\in I$ then $a,b\in S\Rightarrow ab\in S$, and so $ab\not\in I$.

It seems that the first two examples fails because $A\setminus S$ need not be an ideal, and the definition only mentions $A\setminus P$, not $A\setminus S$.

Answer (score 0):

Your examples seem totally right, and your last proof too. One word that I may add is that the exercise becomes less confusing if you reformulate the property in the definition in the following way : 
Let $I$ be an ideal. If $A \setminus I$ is a multiplicative set, then $I$ is prime.